# Can I critically hit a chicken?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently acquired the [Hand of the Prophet](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hand-of-the-prophet) relic for my Enchantress that enables all her skills. As a result she's now polymorphing enemies into chickens, an ability I had never previously used.

I've noticed that when attacking the enemies as chickens, their health bar goes down but critical hit damage numbers never appear over their heads like they do when I normally attack. Does it just not show this for enemies polymorphed into chickens, or is my Enchantress actually doing me a disservice by making these enemies crit-immune for the duration of their polymorph?

Comment: That sounds like an awesome relic!

Comment: @Mkalafut Here is a link to the relic: [Hand of the Prophet](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hand-of-the-prophet)

Comment: @Mkalafut [Undying followers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/enchanting-favor) + [Unity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/unity) is also an amazing combo

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can indeed crit chickens.  You can watch it happen with a few abilities, like the Barbarian's Overpower, with reduce their CD on a crit.  The visual cue on the icon will tick down, even if you're just hitting a chicken.

For some reason, the chickens are coded so that they don't show that combat text.  It seems to just be a funny irregularity.